# C++ Visual Studio Linker Error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors, linker-errors

I made a boolean method which will return true or false. I want to see the actual value it returns, so I tried this in my main method:

```
bool answer = methodName(); // I made sure to include the parameters in my code
cout << answer << endl;
```

It gives me the following error:

```
error LINK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool ___cdec1" methodName(parameters)
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Show the actual code, show us the complete methodName.

Answer (score 1):

The linker is complaining because you *declared* your function `methodName()` but you did not provide a *definition* for it.

Comment: Most likely, although the question is ambiguous - the function in the error message has a different signature to the one he is calling. He claims his real code doesn't do that, but we don't know for sure unless he shows it.

Comment: @JBentley: If the function had an incompatible signature he would get a compiler error, not a linker error.